# How to create a list of dates in kdb in a convenient way?

Tags: kdb

Is there any way I can input two dates and a list of date in between including themselves will be created?

eg.  I would like 2017.01.01 2017.01.02 .... 2017.01.10

What I am doing now is

```
2017.01.01 + til 10
```

but I would like to input something like

```
2017.01.01;2017.01.10
```

and it can have all the list of dates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work

```
{[sd;ed] sd + til 1 + ed - sd}
```

Comment: thanks this is what I wrote too. I was thinking if there is any inbuilt function I can use for.

Comment: No inbuilt function for this - the above is a popular q idiom. Why not add the function to a util script